# How to add pen node in predefined robots in webots

Tags: webots

I wanted to draw the trajectory of epuck robot but can't seem to find how to integrate pen node in predefined robots such as epuck.

Answer (score 0):

Webots PROTOs usually have an extension slot. For example, in the case of the e-puck robot there are `turretSlot` and `groundSensorsSlot` extension slots:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/epuck#e-puck-proto

You can put the Pen node in any of those two. Of course, if the position of those slots is not suitable you can apply rotation/translation to the Pen node.